# How to match a string with double and/or single dash?

Tags: regex, linux, grep

With the following code, I would like to use regex to be able to select `.ptress--a` AND `.ptress--a-l`, and the other classess too.

```
.ptres--a { pointer-events: auto }
.ptres--n { pointer-events: none }

 @media (max-width: 1280px) {
    .ptres--a-l { pointer-events: auto }
    .ptres--n-l { pointer-events: none }
 }  

 @media (max-width: 840px) {
    .ptres--a-m { pointer-events: auto }
    .ptres--n-m { pointer-events: none }
 }

 @media (max-width: 400px) {
    .ptres--a-s { pointer-events: auto }
    .ptres--n-s { pointer-events: none }
 }
```

The regex that I have `\w[\w]*(?:--\w+)` doesn't match the whole string, leaving out the final `-l|m|s` part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a simple regex for your requirement,

`\.\w+--\w+-\w+|.\w+--\w+`

This uses OR to match with either string of the format `.ptres--a-l` OR `.ptres--a`

You can use it in `grep` like this,

```
cat custom.css | grep -E -o '.\w+--\w+-\w+|\w+--\w+'
```